# Backslash escaping behavior depending on usage

Tags: bash

I've been reading the Advanced Bash guide and I'm still stuck at one of the escaping examples (and I haven't been able to find the answer here or on Google).

```
echo `echo \z` # z
echo `echo \\z` # z
echo `echo \\\z` # \z
echo `echo \\\\z` # \z
echo `echo \\\\\\z` # \z
echo `echo \\\\\\\z` # \\z
```

Why does it take 3 backslashes for only 1 to be displayed? Where does the evaluation start from?

From then on it takes 4 backslashes for an additional one to be displayed (so 3 for 1 displayed, 7 for 2, 11 for 3, etc). Why is that? I couldn't find anything on Bash escaping when it comes to command substitution. What are the rules that play here?

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but after some tests, I realized that `echo \`echo \\z\`` and `echo $(echo \\z)` do not have the same behaviour, even though the 2 syntaxes are supposed to be interchangeable, so I am a bit at loss ...

Comment: Interesting links I found after some research, that could help you [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03). Basically, the answer to your question is : don't use backticks for command substitution, as it handles backslashes in a non-obvious manner. `$(...)` should be prefered.

Comment: You should write that as the answer, even if it's not definitive.